# Rotate font type every second, same content

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

I want to have my website title text loop through font styles every second, I am using google fonts so I will have 10 or so fonts that will change. I found something similar and modified it but it uses a 'click' function and it messed with other elements on my site. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blasphemytj/eburb5on/3/) Any suggestions, helpful links, or demos would be appreciated.

need to avoid this:

```
setInterval(function() {

    var e = $.Event("click");
```

Comment: Really? What's the link between your very vague and board question and the bit of funky and obviously non-functional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the reference to a click event and use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through your elements. Put your function inside your interval and change `click` to `each`:

```js
setInterval(function () {

    $('.one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven, .eight, .nine').each(function () {
        this.className = {
            three: 'four',
            four: 'five',
            five: 'six',
            six: 'seven',
            seven: 'eight',
            eight: 'nine',
            nine: 'one',
            one: 'two',
            two: 'three'
        }[this.className];
    });

}, 1000);
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eburb5on/4/)

Comment: This works but still uses far too heavy of code to do the job you're trying to do. If you want to use class names fine, but please don't use JQuery to do something so small unless you're already loading it for other things on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test this, but I think this should pretty much do what I believe you're asking for.

```
var fonts = ["cabin", "roboto slab", "open sans", "open sans condensed", "roboto",      "oswald", "lato"];
var intervalDuration = 1000;
var currentFontIndex = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    $('h1').css('font-family', fonts[currentFontIndex];
    currentFontIndex++;
    if(currentFontIndex == fonts.length){
        currentFontIndex = 0;
    }
}, intervalDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're trying to do you should just set an interval that rotates the font, that's all. Like this:

```
var i = 0;
var fonts = ["Arial", "Times New Roman", "Calibri"];

function changeFont(){
    document.getElementById("siteTitle").style.fontFamily = fonts[i];
    i++;
    if(i > fonts.length) { i = 0; }
}

window.setInterval(changeFont, 1000);
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eburb5on/9/) will show you a working version of your demo. I do praise you for your recognition of the misuse of the click() function of JQuery.

Comment: Btw: this jquery free, you don't need it to do something so small. @Marcel, sorry for posting basically the same thing, I didn't see your post till I was done.